# How to avoid increasing the input value on a type number input when pressing the up button?

Tags: jquery, html

In wondering about how to avoid increasing the input value on a type number input when pressing the up button. Is possible?

Comment: Create an event on the up button and check if the value has reached the max, if so set the value to max.

Answer (score 1):

Its pretty easy to do so without any js code required:

`<input type="number" max="your_max_value"/>`

You can similarly do for minimum

`<input type="number" max="your_max_value" min="your_min_value"/>`

Answer (score 0):

Bind a keypress or keyup event to your input element, and if the key is the up button, prevent default event action.

```
$(input_selector).keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 38 || e.keyCode == 40) {//38 is up arrow , 40 is down arrow.
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```